Emf induction in a conducting coil placed in a variable magnetic field
Consider a conducting coil placed in a variable magnetic field. By the laws of nature, an emf will be induced in the coil. Between which two points is the emf induced in the coil?
If we consider it to be similar to a circuit in which a cell is connected, then in terms of 'energy height diagram' (a plot of amount of energy flowing in the circuit w.r.t the coordinates of the circuit), it comes out to be the first image in the diagram, while the original coil has 'energy height diagram' as the second figure in the diagram, and the two are not compatible.
Then how is the emf induced in the coil? (I agree that there is no such term as emf in a non-conservative field, but just for the consistency with conservative field, I insist on defining such term. Also, we do usually find the emf induced between any two random points in the given coil.) 

This question is open to edit. It would be helpful if someone replaces this image with actual plot.

The question is clear to everyone, I think.
